# Как сделать цвет спрайта зависимым от здоровья(чем меньше хп, тем более красный)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Иерархия обьектов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть обьект ShootingEnemy (растение) у которого есть дочерний обьект img(на нем находится SpriteRenderer). Растение стреляет красными пульками. Игрок стреляет синими, и может ими наносить урон растению. С учетом урона у меня никаких проблем нет, но я хочу сделать чтобы цвет спрайта менялся в зависимости от его хп. То есть, чем меньше хп у растения тем краснее оно будет. Делал это так:

```
void Awake() {
    bullet = Resources.Load<Bullet>("Bullet");
    rb = FindObjectOfType<Hero>().GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
}
void Update() {
    sprite.color = new Color(255, 255f/5*hp, 255f/5*hp);
}
```

в коде ShootingEnemy

Но это не сработало. Решил проверить то, меняется ли цвет спрайта если его самостоятельно поменять в инспекторе Unity, оказалось что, судя по всему, из-за анимации обьекта цвет спрайта постоянно сбрасывается к стандартному. То есть, если поставить красный цвет и только потом запустить игру, то он станет снова белым. То же самое во время игры

Я даже пробовал вешать скрипт на сам обьект **img** (на котором отображается спрайт и анимация) но ничего не сработало:

```
public class ShootingEnemyChild : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int hp;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private ShootingEnemy parent;
    void Start()
    {
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        parent = transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<ShootingEnemy>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        hp = parent.hp;
        sprite.color = new Color(255, (255/5)*hp, (255/5)*hp);
    }
}
```

Как можно исправить эту проблему и можно ли вообще реализовать эту идею(без создания новых анимаций)?

Comment: я думаю, что вам поможет [градиент](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html)

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, в Unity Color принимает только числа от 0 до 1, то есть если использовать мою задумку то цвет будет либо белым(стандартным) так как числа будут (255, 51, 51) либо полностью красным. Я поменял формулу на (1f, hp/5, hp/5) и теперь все работает.

```
sprite.color = new Color(1f, hp/3, hp/3, 1f);
```